# C# WPF Ribbon and MDI Window

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon, mdi

I'm trying to build a little application, with a ribbon and MDI windows.
I need to be able to open/resize/close "sub windows" into the main window. The main window is the one that have the ribbon.
For exemple, what I ant to do is similar than Excel when you open multiple workbooks.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/

> **Project Description** 
>   A library to add the traditional Windows Forms
>   Multiple Document Interface (MDI) features to WPF. The aim is to
>   resemble the original as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you with Excel kind of MDI properties.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3553/Introduction-to-MDI-Forms-with-C